# Second-order polynomial with cosine as a factor: Numeric vs. Analytic solution

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, numerical-methods

I want to do the following *seemingly* simple thing:

Solve $$E = x + x^2\lambda\cos(3\phi)$$ with $x$ being **positively defined number** and $\lambda$ some small and irrelevant number (for dimensional reasons).

In essence, for a fixed constant value of $E$, I want to map each angles $\phi \in [0, 2\pi)$ to a real and positive $x$ value. (I am aware that I only need $[0, 2\pi/3)$ but for simplicity let's use $2\pi$)

The problem is the following though: Solving this numerically and analytically just doesn't give the same results.

I *know* that the solution $x$ oscillates around the value $E$ with frequency $2\pi/3$. I have also proven this numerically, just by calculating the solution of the equation numerically (while **having** the constraint of $x>0$). What I do is simply start from a small value of $x>0$ and increase it until the equation is satisfied (for a given $\phi$).

My problem is that when I try to solve this expression analytically, I run intro trouble! Let $a = \lambda\cos(3\phi)$, and
$$ \chi = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1 + 4\alpha E}}{2\alpha}$$
be the solution. This is of course valid only for $a\neq0$. But this is not the problem. The problem is that solutions get arbitrary large when $a$ gets close to zero. This does not happen for the numeric solution. If necessary I can also upload figures which show the analytic and numeric solutions plotted together.

The numeric solution is simply: [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFcR1.png), where I have used actual values for $E, \lambda$.

So the question is: **How can I get the numerical solution analytically, given that I know that $x>0$?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you will get one very large solution if the quadratic coefficient is close to zero, this simply because by the product part of Vietes formula the product of both roots is $E/α$.

You just need to select the small root, if possible with a numerically stable formula. As it happens, this exists for quadratic equations by way of the binomial formulas in that the solutions can also be written as 
$$
\chi=\frac{2E}{1\pm\sqrt{1+4αE}}
$$
where then the "$+$" solution close to $E$ or one order better $\dfrac{E}{1+αE}+O(α^2)= E-αE^2+O(α^2)$ is the one you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I Will test it right-away! You use two symbols, $\alpha$ and $a$ in the formula. What is $a$? (simply a typo?)

Comment: This is some edit error when I replaced the original $a$ with $α$.

Comment: I got about your graph with the  "+" formula and with $E=0.76$ and $λ=-0.11$.

Comment: Yeah works perfectly fine, thanks!